# MySQL,OUTFILE: Is it possible to store query result into a variable instead of a file

Tags: php, mysql, permissions, backup, database-backups

I am trying to backup a table records with `php`. I use the following code to get data:

```
 $table_name = "my_table";
 $backup_file  = dirname(__FILE__)."/backup/my_table.sql";
 $sql = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backup_file' FROM $table_name";
 $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
```

But, the last line gives the following error:

***Access denied for user 'user_name'@'10.1.1.9' (using password: YES)***

I changed the file permission for `backup` directory and its files to `777`. But still the same error exists.

Now, I want to know, in the **SELECT * INTO OUTFILE** , is it possible to store the backup data into a variable (instead of the file). So then I can store that variable into a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Access denied for user 'user_name'@'10.1.1.9' (using password: YES)

This error is not for denied access to the file system, but for the database.
You are trying to connect to the database with a user named `user_name` and a password. And it does not have access (wrong name or password maybe?).

If you rather wan't to store the result of the query into a variable, you can do this by removing the `INTO OUTFILE` part of the query:

```
"SELECT * FROM $table_name"
```

---

While we are at it, I would recommend you to stop use the `mysql_*` API provided by older versions of PHP. Its a bad and deprecated API and will be removed in future releases.
Take a look at `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

You are not really "backing up" the table.  You are simply copying its contents.  If that is sufficient for what you want to accomplish, then just read the records back, one at a time, and write them to a file.  This is a php loop.

The problem that you are facing is that the server does not have permissions on the directory where the file is located.  Perhaps there is a way to give the server permissions or to use a common file system, mounted on both the server and client computers.

"Backup" and "recovery" are concepts that are applied to entire *databases* and all the contents in them, including tables, table structures, constraints, views, stored procedures, user defined functions, triggers, and so on.  You can read more about the built-in capabilities [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-and-recovery.html).

Comment: I chmod'ed the backup directory to 777, then why does not server have the necessary permissions to write the file?

Comment: @Ormoz . . . The server probably doesn't even see the file system, or perhaps not as you do.  You need to name it from the perspective of the server.